# How to search psql array elements by index in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

In my rails psql application I have an emails array column. The element in the first index of this column is the primary email. I want to be able to search the db for all people with primary email x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to test for array inclusion. Just get the first element and compare that to the string:

```rb
User.where("emails[1] = ?", "x@test.com")
```

Comment: Thanks, easier to understand. I did some Benchmark.measure to compare with the Array inclusion answer and there seems to be little difference in Performance.

Answer (score 0):

I could not see this in the documentation but thanks to [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94639/delete-array-element-by-index) I can see that in Postgres 9.5 or older you can use

`arr[1:1]`

syntax to look only in the first element

So this is the answer

`User.where("emails[1:1] @> ARRAY[?]", "x@test.com")`